# Windows 10 doesn't start after setting up dual boot with Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, uefi, windows, boot-repair

I installed Ubuntu 20.04 alongside Windows 10; after restarting, however, I was met with a bluescreen and error code 0xc0000001 when trying to boot into Windows. At times I have also gotten the error code 0xc0000098 ("boot configuration data file doesn't contain valid information for an operating system").

I've successfully set up dual boot before, although not on this machine. I've tried a lot of solutions suggested online, but have come up empty-handed so far.

Thankfully, Ubuntu 20.04 appears to work without error. Before installing Ubuntu, I was using Windows 10 for roughly one year on this machine.

Some additional details:

- Both operating systems are installed in EFI mode.
- Windows Startup Repair is unable to find a solution
- I have two drives (one HDD, one SSD). Ubuntu 20.04 is entirely on a partition of the HDD, while Windows 10 is installed on the SSD with user files on the HDD. The EFI partition is on the HDD.

Here is the most recent output of boot-repair, run from an Ubuntu live USB: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/QT2tnd4m3J/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Boot this directly from UEFI, it will just say Windows.

```
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager
```

You have Windows hibernated or fast start up on, which also sets hibernation flag.

```
> The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0). Metadata kept in
> Windows cache, refused to mount.
```

Grub only boots working Windows, or Windows that is not hibernated.

[Unable to mount Windows 10 partition; it "is in an unsafe state"](http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions)

[Unable to mount Windows (NTFS) filesystem due to hibernation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/145902/unable-to-mount-windows-ntfs-filesystem-due-to-hibernation)

Comment: Somehow, this worked despite having tried it before. I thought I had already disabled fast startup (perhaps startup repair reenabled it?), but I booted from UEFI and was able to successfully boot into Windows. I disabled fast startup, and booting through grub worked the next time I tried it.

Comment: Windows  turns fast startup back on with updates. So if grub does not boot Windows, check again.