# Ubuntu dual boot: First Grub didn't show. Then it showed with a Windows menu. But more problems.. "invalid UEFI"

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, uefi, windows-10, boot-repair

I am a newbie in the Ubuntu territory. I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on my Windows 10 PC for dual boot. I have three SSDs. I installed Ubuntu in one of them. (I followed this instruction: https://www.tecmint.com/install-ubuntu-alongside-with-windows-dual-boot/. But I didn't’ create the /home partition.) The Windows is in another SSD. The last SSD is just for saving some personal data.

**I have three problems:**

1. When I rebooted the system after installation, Grub didn’t show up. I wanted a dual-boot, so I searched for an answer. I found that I had to edit /etc/default/grub file (e.g., [Why is Grub menu not shown when starting my computer?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/182248/why-is-grub-menu-not-shown-when-starting-my-computer)). I did it, and Grub showed up.
   [Grup shows up](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X4PK6.jpg)
2. But now I didn’t see a Windows 10 menu in the Grub window. I searched for an answer again and modified as advised here: [GRUB does not detect Windows](https://askubuntu.com/questions/197868/grub-does-not-detect-windows). I was able to see a Windows 10 menu in the Grub window.
3. But when I clicked on the Windows 10 menu, Grub said something like “**invalid UEFI.**”

**Here are some things about my system that I think might help you to understand it.**

1. I found that there is no file in the /efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot folder. Is this related to the third problem above, "invalid UEFI"?
2. When I clicked on the ubuntu menu on Grub, it often took forever to boot. It seems that the system froze there. To avoid, I had to remove the Grub menu by again changing the /etc/default/grub file. I changed GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=menu -> GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden. Then, ubuntu boots normally.
3. When I clicked the Advanced options for Ubuntu on the Grub screen, I find two different “versions” of Linux. One is Linux 5.4.0-42-generic, and the other is 5.4.0-52-generic. (I installed and deleted ubuntu several times already before this round. Is this the reason that I see two different versions?).
   [Two different "versions" of linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iz9oC.jpg)
4. This may be related to 3) just above. When I type `sudo update-grub`, the system says that it finds two images. See the screenshot.
   [Two images of linux](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pMY7R.jpg). (In fact, I had to install and unistall ubuntu several times before.)
5. Finally, when I want to boot Windows (after using Ubuntu), Windows goes through the disk checking process. It boots normally, but it goes through the process anyway. Is this normal?
   [Windows goes through a disk-check process](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxzop.jpg)
6. Finally, my BIOS shows three booting options: One ubuntu and two Windows 10.

I can still dual-boot by changing the boot order in the BIOS setup every time I want to use the other system. But entering the BIOS when I want to use the other system is not convenient. I want to use Grub. But I have the three problems above. I would appreciate if anyone could help me to resolve these issues. Finally and if I am bit more ambitious, I would like to make Windows the "default" OS in Grub. Is this possible?

Comment: Make sure Windows fast start up is off: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288661/windows-10-doesnt-start-after-setting-up-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-20-04/1288764#1288764 It is normal for Ubuntu to keep two kernels. So if new one has issues, you can boot old one. Do you have two separate ESP - efi system partitions? Windows has to have boot files in an ESP, unless it is BIOS boot. Then you cannot boot Windows from grub as UEFI & BIOS are not compatible. or grub can only boot other installs in same boot mode.

Comment: Thanks, @oldfred. I disabled fast start up. I didn't understand the second part of your comment--the ESP thing (Windows has to have boot files in an ESP.) Can you direct me to a webpage that I can learn about ESP and Windows boot from? Thank you.

Comment: Lets see details, use ppa version with your live installer (2nd option) or any working install,  not Boot-Repair ISO:
Please copy & paste the pastebin link to the Boot-info summary report ( do not post report), do not run the auto fix till reviewed.
 https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair Windows ESP or UEFI system partition: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/configure-uefigpt-based-hard-drive-partitions#RecommendedPartitionConfigurations &  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI