# Cannot Dual-boot ubuntu 20.10 on nvme SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd, windows-10

I would like to dual boot ubuntu 20.10 alongside Windows 10 education. When I use the installer it only recognizes my secondary HDD as opposed to my primary SSD.
[image]

I know that ubuntu recognizes that my ssd exists on the system because if I select that I want to create my own partitions it recognizes that the system has an ssd.
[image]

I have seen questions that pointed to unrecognized drives being caused by secure boot or RAID mode. My bios settings say my system is in AHCI and I have disabled fast startup and secure boot so I do not believe these are the issues. I would prefer to not have to create the partitions myself as I am a newcomer to linux and would prefer the auto-installer I also do not want to use the HDD for performance reasons. Why isnt ubuntu recognizing my primary drive and how do get a dual boot functional on the SSD.

Any help is appreciated! Thank you!

Comment: What brand/model system? Have you updated UEFI and SSD firmware? Is Windows fast startup off? Have you created unallocated space on SSD for Ubuntu to install into? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288661/windows-10-doesnt-start-after-setting-up-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-20-04/1288764#1288764 & 
http://askubuntu.com/questions/843153/ubuntu-16-showing-windows-10-partitions &

Comment: It's a gigabyte mobo and windows fast startup is off. Do I need to creat unallocated space? I thought the auto installer is meant to create the partition. How do I update uefi and ssd firmware?

Comment: Always better to use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions. While gparted or installer usually works, when it does not users blame Linux, but almost always a Windows issue that using Windows would have resolved. You go into UEFI can check version, then go to vendors site for support and look for BIOS/UEFI updates for your model. Many vendors still call it BIOS even though UEFI. SSD vendors also have update software in their support sites.  Mine is a z170, so I use this, https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GA-Z170X-UD3-rev-10/support#support-dl-driver

Comment: So shrink the partition in windows. Free up the space and then run the installer?

Comment: Unless you have updated UEFI, SSD firmware, tuned off Windows fast start up and have drives in AHCI mode, may then you correctly see drive.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Answer (score 0):

Sorry dude I can't find specifics on it, But I think it might of been a problem I encountered when trying to format .and partition my windows 10 drive is I remember right. It wasn't allowing me to do it. I remember it taking me like 2 days of ok it failed, oh have to adjust another setting not mentioned. Sorry I'm not more help. I've tried looking it up.

Answer (score 0):

I created a new partition with easeUS. Once I had done this and all the steps listed in the question I got an option when using the auto installer to use the free partition. The solution was just creating a free partition beforehand and letting ubuntu use it instead of make it.