# Windows 10 not booting after dual boot

Tags: dual-boot, 18.04, windows-10

I am not very familiar with Linux so please bear with me.

I have tried to dual boot my Windows 10 machine with Ubuntu 18.04. After succesfully installing Ubuntu using the "install alongside windows" option, I can no longer boot into Windows. In Grub there is still a windows boot manager option, however, when I select that option, it takes me to the windows recovery. There it shows me error code 0xc0000001. As an additional note, Ubuntu works fine and I can still see my windows files in the file explorer in Ubuntu.

I have tried the following thing without succces:

- bootrec /fixmbr and bootrec /fixboot on windows installation media
- boot-repair in Ubuntu (summary: http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wKtNZ5KKxr/)
- sudo update-grub

Any advice would be appreciated!

SOLVED: I just reset windows in the recovery (did not lose any files)

Comment: Post link to summary report from Boot-Repair.

Comment: Here you go:http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/wKtNZ5KKxr/

Comment: Grub only boots working Windows. Does booting Windows directly from UEFI boot entry work. If not then just a Windows issue & you need Windows repairs. If it does, you probably have Windows fast start up/hibernation on. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1288661/windows-10-doesnt-start-after-setting-up-dual-boot-with-ubuntu-20-04/1288764#1288764  You also show grub BIOS boot loader in gpt's protective MBR. You have UEFI installs & UEFI system and never should turn on or use BIOS/Legacy/CSM mode as that just causes more issue. The grub in MBR should not otherwise cause issues.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt install os-prober
sudo os-prober
sudo update-grub
```

Comment: I just tried this, it still does not work